# Calculating the L2 inner product in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, inner-product

I'm thinking about the L2 inner product.

[image]

I am specifically interested in performing these calculations using numpy/scipy. The best I have come up with is performing an array-based integral such as `numpy.trapz`.

```
import numpy as np
n=100000.
h=1./n
X = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,n)

def L2_inner_product(f,g):
    return np.trapz(f*g,dx=2*np.pi*h)/np.pi

print L2_inner_product(np.sin(X), np.sin(X))
print L2_inner_product(np.cos(2*X), np.cos(2*X))
print L2_inner_product(np.sin(X), np.cos(X))
print L2_inner_product(np.sin(X), np.cos(3*X))
print L2_inner_product(np.ones(n),np.ones(n))

0.99999
0.99999
-3.86525742539e-18
1.6565388966e-18
1.99998
```

To be clear, I am not interested in using Mathematica, Sage, or Sympy. I am specifically interested in numpy/scipy, in which I am exploring the numpy "array space" as a finite subspace of Hilbert Space. Within these parameters, have others implemented an L2 inner product, perhaps using `numpy.inner` or `numpy.linalg.norm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to speed, `numpy.inner` is probably the best choice for fixed `n`. `numpy.trapz` should be converging faster though. Either way, if you are worried about speed, you should also take into account the evaluation of the functions themselves will also take some time.

Below some simple benchmark I ran using different inner product implementations.

### Timings

The plot below shows the runtime for the computation of only the integral, i.e. not the function evaluation. While `numpy.trapz` is a constant factor slower, `numpy.inner` is as fast as calling BLAS dirrectly. As Ophion pointed out, `numpy.inner` calls BLAS internally probably with some overhead for input checking.
[image: Runtime for the computation of the sum of the products in the inner product.]

It is also interesting to look at the time it takes to evaluate the function itself, which has of course to be done to compute the inner product. Below a plot that shows the evaluation for standard transcendental functions `numpy.sin`, `numpy.sqrt` and `numpy.exp`. The scaling is of course the same for the evaluation and the summing of the products and the overall time required is comparable

[image: Runtime for the function evaluation in the inner product.]

#### Error

Finally, one should also consider the accuracy of the different methods, and it's here where it actually gets interesting. Below a plot of the convergence of the different implementation for the computation of [image: \langle exp(x),exp(x) \rangle]. Here we can see that `numpy.trapz` actually scales much better than the other two implementations, which don't even reach machine precision before I run out of memory.

[image]

#### Conclusion

Considering the bad convergence properties of `numpy.inner`, I would go for `numpy.trapz`. But even then a lot of integration nodes are required to get satisfactory accuracy. Since your integration domain is fixed you might even try going for higher order quadratures.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sls
from scipy.linalg.blas import ddot
import timeit

## Define inner product.
def l2_inner_blas( f, g, dx ):
    return ddot( f, g )*dx / np.pi

def l2_inner( f, g, dx ):
    return np.inner( f, g )*dx / np.pi

def l2_inner_trapz( f, g, dx ):
    return np.trapz(f*g,dx=dx) / np.pi

sin1 = lambda x: np.sin( x )
sin2 = lambda x: np.sin( 2.0 * x)

## Timing setups.
setup1 = "import numpy as np; from __main__ import l2_inner,"
setup1 += "l2_inner_trapz, l2_inner_blas, sin1, sin2;"
setup1 += "n=%d; x=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,n); dx=2.0*np.pi/(n-1);"
setup1 += "f=sin1(x); g=sin2(x);"

def time( n ):
    setupstr = setup1 % n
    time1 = timeit.timeit( 'l2_inner( f, g, dx)', setupstr, number=10 )
    time2 = timeit.timeit( 'l2_inner_blas( f, g, dx)', setupstr, number=10 )
    time3 = timeit.timeit( 'l2_inner_trapz( f, g, dx)', setupstr, number=10 )
    return (time1, time2, time3)

setup2 = "import numpy as np; x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,%d);"
def time_eval( n ):
    setupstr = setup2 % n
    time_sin = timeit.timeit( 'np.sin(x)', setupstr, number=10 )
    time_sqrt = timeit.timeit( 'np.sqrt(x)', setupstr, number=10 )
    time_exp = timeit.timeit( 'np.exp(x)', setupstr, number=10 )
    return (time_sin, time_sqrt, time_exp)

## Perform timing for vector product.
times = np.zeros( (7,3) )
for i in range(7):
    times[i,:] = time( 10**(i+1) )

x = 10**np.arange(1,8,1)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set( xscale='log', yscale='log', title='Inner vs. BLAS vs. trapz', \
        ylabel='time [s]', xlabel='n')
ax.plot( x, times[:,0], label='numpy.inner' )
ax.plot( x, times[:,1], label='scipy.linalg.blas.ddot')
ax.plot( x, times[:,2], label='numpy.trapz')
plt.legend()

## Perform timing for function evaluation.
times_eval = np.zeros( (7,3) )
for i in range(7):
    times_eval[i,:] = time_eval( 10**(i+1) )

x = 10**np.arange(1,8,1)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set( xscale='log', yscale='log', title='sin vs. sqrt vs. exp', \
        ylabel='time [s]', xlabel='n')
ax.plot( x, times_eval[:,0], label='numpy.sin' )
ax.plot( x, times_eval[:,1], label='numpy.sqrt')
ax.plot( x, times_eval[:,2], label='numpy.exp' )
plt.legend()

## Test convergence.
def error( n ):
    x = np.linspace( -np.pi, np.pi, n )
    dx = 2.0 * np.pi / (n-1)
    f = np.exp( x )
    l2 = 0.5/np.pi*(np.exp(2.0*np.pi) - np.exp(-2.0*np.pi))
    err1 = np.abs( (l2 - l2_inner( f, f, dx )) / l2)
    err2 = np.abs( (l2 - l2_inner_blas( f, f, dx )) / l2)
    err3 = np.abs( (l2 - l2_inner_trapz( f, f, dx )) / l2)
    return (err1, err2, err3)

acc = np.zeros( (7,3) )
for i in range(7):
    acc[i,:] = error( 10**(i+1) )

x = 10**np.arange(1,8,1)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( x, acc[:,0], label='numpy.inner' )
ax.plot( x, acc[:,1], label='scipy.linalg.blas.ddot')
ax.plot( x, acc[:,2], label='numpy.trapz')
ax.set( xscale='log', yscale='log', title=r'$\langle \exp(x), \exp(x) \rangle$', \
        ylabel='Relative Error', xlabel='n')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: `np.inner` is calling ddot under the hood, your just avoiding the overhead of the inner function.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I suspected it but the "documentation" doesn't really say anything about it.

Comment: I find the numpy/scipy documentation quite lacking in details. Especially as we are tiptoeing around blas/lapack, it would be nice to have more access to the inner workings without cracking open the libraries.

Comment: I really appreciate the thoughtful answer, as well as its thorough presentation.